# Need to display Flowchart in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight

Iam trying to develop a silverlight application that displays a flowchart to the user.

All the information required to display the flowchart is supplied from SQL Server DB.
ie we would have multiple tables in the DB to completeltly describe the flowchart.

ie a ControlItems Table that has the details bout all the items in the table ( process box , decision box  etc) 
There would be another Relations table that specifies the relation between various controlItems that is used to display the flowchart in the screen.

The application reads the tables and displays the flowchart.
Is anyone aware any similar application so that I can refer that ?

Note - Unlike most of the applications there I do not need to drag and drop controlitems and then draw a connection between them.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [this](http://www.aspose.com/.net/diagram-component.aspx)?

Aspose.Diagram for .NET works for us.

> Aspose.Diagram is a class library for working with Microsoft Visio
>   files. It allows developers to work with VSD, VSDX, VSS, VST, VSX,
>   VTX, VDW and VDX files on C#, VB.NET, ASP.NET web applications, web
>   services, Mono and Windows applications. It allows you to open files
>   and manipulate the elements of the diagram, from lines and fills, to
>   more complex elements, and then export to VDX, VSX, VTX, XPS, HTML,
>   SVG, SWF, XAML, image or PDF formats.
>
> The class library is an alternative to the Microsoft Visio Object
>   Model and provides a better performance. It makes use of the advanced
>   functionality of Visio Services to manipulate Visio documents on a
>   server. The API is extensible, easy to use and compact. It provides
>   common functionality so that developers have to write less code when
>   performing common tasks.
>
> Aspose.Diagram is aimed at developers who need to work with Visio
>   files from within their own applications. It allows developers to
>   manipulate the file format quickly and easily, saving time and effort
>   in developing a solution for working with Visio files.

However, you'd have to make Visio files which are stored in the database vs on the fly viewing of database objects and their relationships.  I don't know if that's a problem or not - within your scope.